# What is the correct way to rename/swap a table in production

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have two tables, `tblCode` and `tblCodeAlternative`

`tblCode` has about 4100 rows and is used in production.

`tblCodeAlternative` has about 4200 rows and is in the production database but not used anywhere.

What I need to do is swap the contents of the above database so `tblCode` becomes `tblCodeAlternative` and `tblCodeAlternative` becomes `tblCode`.

So really what I want to do is swap the contents of the two tables. I have tried to rename `tblCode` to `tblCodeTemp`, then rename `tblCodeAlternative` to `tblCode` and lastly rename `tblCodeTemp` to `tblCodeAlternative`.

However, for some reason this makes some of the application fail. The database itself is not producing any errors, in fact the renaming is surprisingly quick.

I'm not entirely sure why parts of the application is failing. If I revert the renaming then it all works again.

To rule out any mistakes on the database side, is it OK to rename a table the way I have done, or should it be done in another more robust way? I realise that for a few seconds there is no table called `tblCode` which is used in the application.

Comment: What errors are being generated?  Can you post the DDL of both tables?  Seems to me that there is either a column name difference or a datatype difference.

Comment: @datagod You made me check the column names, datatypes and keys. It seems like I forgot to add a primary key to the alternative table! I will try and correct that. But should I still rename the same way I have done before? Is that safe?

Comment: Sure, you can rename, or use schemas to transfer as I do here: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo and here: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2

Comment: Double check your permissions too.  The permissions will stay with the existing table regardless of name.

Comment: The three step approach you are using is one I have used successfully in the past.  Make sure you do this when there are no other processes using the tables, and you should have no problem.

Comment: To everyone who's answered @datagod, aaron Betrand and Kenneth Fisher, I don't think the actual renaming is the issue here. I'm getting the errors due to some other inconsistency somewhere. 

However, could you still post an answer to the best robust way of renaming a table? Whether it be the simply way that I have done it or throught the stored procedure way it would be great to know the pro/cons and your experiences with doing both! I'm sure it will be useful in the future as well. Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe you could elaborate in your question how *you* did the renaming (exactly what commands or tools you used). All the more so since you've already been pointed to a couple of renaming methods.